# Write html block as a string

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display the html as the user entered it in a textarea (using Javascript) . Like this :

```
Every thing fine <a href="/toto"> link </a>
```

How can i do that without using a "pre" tag? I just want to avoid html interpretation.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a string:

```
str='Every thing fine <a href="/toto"> link </a>';
```

you replace the brackets:

```
str.replace('<', '&lt;').replace('>', '&gt;');
```

then write in to the document:

```
document.write(str);
```

or set an existing elements content:

```
elem.innerHTML = str;
```

Comment: In fact i used the _.escape function of underscore.js

Answer (score 5):

Just create a text node…

```
var node = document.createTextNode(a_string);
```

… and add it to the document somewhere…

```
document.body.appendChild(node);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the textContent.

```
elem.textContent = "<div>foo</div>";
```

---

But for browser compatibility, you should do something like this at the start of your code:

```
var textContent = ('textContent' in document) ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';
```

And then use it like this:

```
elem[textContent] = "<div>foo</div>";
```

Answer (score -2):

[jQuery.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) will do this for you

Comment: No, it won't. It will parse the HTML.

Comment: As description says: "Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements".

Comment: You should read the question again. OP wants to display the HTML markup that was entered in a `textarea` element. Either way, there's no indication that jQuery is being used here.

Comment: The OP said he wanted to display HTML as it was entered by the user. I can only assume this was encoded. He/she also said they wanted to use Javascript to do this. @Franky, html() also sets.